# UnitTest EF Core InMemoryDatabase - row ID mismatch in basic CRUD operations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a Visual Studio 2017 .NET Core 2.0 project with EF Core as the ORM for talking to the database.
I am trying to use XUnit to do a simple test of the DBContext that was created.

But have come across this problem that occurs only when selecting RunAll in which it occurs every time. But if I do a single test or add all tests to a playlist and run all it doesn't reproduce and the test passes.

Now the problem is in the TestGet() method below is that when I do a service.Create (dbcontext.add) it returns the ID of 1 every time.
But when I then call the data for ID 1 using service.Get(id) it returns null, and if I do a service.GetAll() it returns a single item that actually has an ID of 2.

How could the service be returning an ID of 1 even though the inMemoryDB actually created it with the ID 2 and that it only occurs when doing a RunAll test.

All code required should be below. Please note its been redacted and pasted from multiple files.

```
    public class TestClass
    {
        [Fact]
        public async void TestGet()
        {
            using (var context = new CoreContext(CoreInMemoryDbContextOptions.Get()))
            {
                var _testService = new TestService(context);
                var newTest = new Test 
                {
                    Name = "Test",
                };
                var itemId = await _testService.Create(newTest); //returns ID 1

                var items = await _testService.GetAll(); //returns single item with ID 2
                var item = await _testService.Get(itemId); //NullException
                Assert.Equal("Test", item.Name);
            }
        }
    }

    public class TestService
    {
        private CoreContext _context;
        public TestService(CoreContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public async Task<Data.Test> Get(int id)
        {
            return await _context.Tests.Where(x => x.TestId == id).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
        }

        public async Task<int> Create(Test component)
        {
            component.TestId = 0;
            _context.Tests.Add(component);
            return await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }


    public class CoreInMemoryDbContextOptions
    {
        public static DbContextOptions<CoreContext> Get()
        {
            DbContextOptions<CoreContext> options;
            var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<CoreContext>();
            builder.UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
            options = builder.Options;

            CoreContext coreContext = new CoreContext(options);
            coreContext.Database.EnsureDeleted();
            coreContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
            return options;
        }
    }
```

Comment: First off, you are **not** doing an **unit test**. Unit test is with mocked dependencies testing of a unit of code (typically a method). When you require external dependencies (and in memory db context is one) its an integration test. Second: What are you even supposed to test? That the dbcontext returns an id? You dont have to test that, microsoft did this already when they made ef core. you should test **YOUR** code not code of others

Comment: @Tseng Mate, I've stripped out a ton of code to get to my reproducible problem. My method unit test I am testing in my logic layer is breaking when its making a call through to my data layer. There is validation and other work that is going on and the unit test (not integration test) that I am trying to test but its falling apart here when it reaches out to the In Memory DB. 

Im not really keen to post the full code here, and ive surely placed enough information here for someone to help out with the problem rather than get attacked over specifics. Not everyone here is day one programming...

Comment: Why are you testing 3rd party dependencies?

Comment: Yea, but if your test needs DbContext its already an integration test. For an unit test you'd have a service which gets an repository interface injected such as `IUserRepository` and operates on it. Here you can mock (i.e. Moq framework)  `IUserRepository` to return arbitrary results. No external system involved. And you shouldn't rely on "auto-incremented" values in unit tests,  its a database concern. your app shouldn't matter if what next number may be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding of the return value of `SaveChangesAsync` is flawed. You're assuming in your test that it returns the id. That's wrong. It returns the count of successful operations, which because you're saving a single entity, is 1. It is always 1. If you want the id, you need to get it from your PK property after the save. EF will backfill that property with the id that was created, but it doesn't return the id directly.

Comment: Thanks, first time working with EF. Had completely overlooked that it wasn’t returning the ID.